# Python write file content from requests response to corresponding file

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an API service which responds with the file content in byte string and extension of the file. I need to write this response to the corresponding file based on the extension. The problem is I have to work with a lot of file types including pdf, pkl, sav, csv etc. I can't find a generic solution to tackle this problem

for csv files I am doing:

```
data = response.content.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
print(data)
import csv,re
with open("tet.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = '\t')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(re.split('\s+',line))
```

for pdf files:

```
with open('hh.pdf','wb') as fd:
     fd.write(oR.content)
```

cant seem to get a generic solution to tackle this problem. 
Any help is appeciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? All of these are different file types, and so they have to be handled by different libraries which are able to work with the format. Only csv files are stored as raw text (although I'm not sure what .sav is), so the others cannot be read plainly

Comment: @awarrier99 thanks for responding, i figured out the  issue, it was because the incoming response.content was of binary format. i just needed to write it as binary.

Answer (score 0):

The incoming response.content from api is of binary format, so irrespective of file type it just needs to be written in the binary format

```
with open(f'file.{extension}', 'w+b') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```